# Generate and read password protected ZIP with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, zip

With Angular / Javascript a password protected ZIP file should be generated.

JSZip cannot generate or read password protected files. Is there a workaround or other tools that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `archiver` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) in combination with `archiver-zip-encrypted` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver-zip-encrypted). It also comes with types for TypeScript (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/archiver).

This is a solution if you work on desktop application and have adjusted your pipeline, a web application will not have an access to the filesystem.